# Waiting for Ajax to be finished with selenium-webdriver in node

Tags: javascript, node.js, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have a single page application and am writing integration tests. I am using the selenium-webdriver, using the **node API** (no Java).

When the user clicks on a button, an AJAX call is initiated. I would like to check what returns from that AJAX call.

Not sure it's relevant: I am not using JQuery, but Polymer (`iron-ajax` to be exact).

I have found some documentation online, but nothing specific for node.

Comment: have you checked bluebird library

Comment: Your code trials please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without getting into specifics of `node.js`, there is no single way to reliably determine that an ajax based resource has been fully loaded. In such case, what you need to do, is to create a combination of certain rules that in summary will be used to "detect" a full page load. Just few examples that can be used together to confirm fully loaded page:

1. If there are any certain areas that you know will only be fully visible after a page has loaded.
2. Any spinners or wait signs that appear on a page while it is still loaded.
3. Use jQuery to assess page load status.

All the above (but possibly more or less) should be used together as a combination.

Comment: It's possible to reliably determine that an ajax based resource has been fully loaded by hooking `XMLHttpRequest` with a script injection.

Comment: @FlorentB. This is correct for a single resource. Not for a whole page that might and will contain multiple elements that load independently.

Comment: @Eugene S, it's also possible with the whole page with elements loading independently.

Comment: @FlorentB. Would you like to explain how it works in a bit more detail in a separate answer? I would love to know how that can work on a page with multiple portlets that load asynchronously.